# How to import amazon workmail in the gmail web client?

Tags: gmail, amazon-web-services

I want to import amazon workmail in my gmail web client.

It seems that gmail requires pop3 access for this and that gmail does not support imap where amazon workmail only supports imap, no pop3.

Is this correct and if so is there a workaround solution?

Thanks in advance! Wouter

Answer (score 1):

I've found a good workaround solution for you, forwarding/redirecting your amazon workmail to gmail.

There is a quite simple workaround.

1. Go to Settings -> Email Rules -> New
2. Define a name for the rule ("Forward All" seems logic)
3. Select Active Rule
4. Go to Conditions and select Includes these words in the sender’s address from de drop-down.
5. Click on "Select words" and write @, click Add button and finally the Ok button.
6. Go to Actions and select Forward the message to and the desired email address.
   (in this step I actually selected the 'Redirect the message to...', that way I
   received the original email and not a forward message, I found that better)
7. Click Ok in the main modal and finally click Save changes.

With this single rule, every single email will be redirected because every sender's address will have @.

This solutions was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57604835/2342414).

Here is another [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57604835/2342414) on the subject.